# how to add additional reachability metadata when working with native:compile

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I have a Spring Boot project that depends on a local JAR package. This local JAR package uses a lot of reflections, in order to package my app to native image, I generated reachability metadata (by using tracing agent) for it.

I use the native-maven-plugin and `mvn -P native native:compile` command to package my Spring Boot project into a native image. How can I configure the native-maven-plugin to use the reachability metadata that I generated?